# Totaling cells over multiple tabs perhaps NOT in the same position, but with same name

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel document with different tabs for each month that has totals paid from individuals. Not all months have the same individuals, as some are added or removed. Is there a way to make a sheet that totals all 12 tabs for Bob Smith, John Doe, etc? I know there's a way to sum over tabs using the same cell positions, but this won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PivotTable to summarize data across multiple tabs in a single worksheet.

1. Click on a cell where you want to insert your PivotTable
2. Press **Alt+D+P** to bring up the Pivot Table Wizard
3. In step 1 of the wizard, select **Multiple consolidation ranges** and then click **Next >**
4. In step 2a of the wizard, select **Create a single page field for me** and then click **Next >**
5. Leave the wizard open, go to your first tab, select the data you want to summarize, and then click **Add** in the PivotTable wizard.
6. Repeat step 5 for the remaining 11 tabs and then click Finish in the wizard.

At this point, you'll have all 12 tabs summarized in a single table. Put the person's name in the **Row Labels** section and put the totals paid in the **Values** section, summarized by Sum to get the total across all tabs.